# Detecting Sdcard in android?

Tags: android, sd-card, android-sdcard

I am using the following code to access sdcard if mounted else using the internal memory:

```
 if( android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
    {       
        //File file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        videoPath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/cue_learn_data/video_files/"+VIDEO_FILENAME+".mp4";

    }
    else
     {

     videoPath="/cue_learn_data/video_files/"+VIDEO_FILENAME+".mp4";

     }
```

But vidoePath is not found when I use first condition.Could anyone help?

Comment: did you verify that this is a valid path on your phone?

Comment: Show us how do you initialize VIDEO_FILENAME.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try doing it in this way:

```
String tmp = "/cue_learn_data/video_files/"+VIDEO_FILENAME+".mp4";
File myFile= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), tmp);

if(myFile.exists()){
    //further processing as your file exists
}
else{
    //seems like your file doesnt exist
}
```

Comment: this is a much better approach.

Answer (score 3):

```
   public static boolean isSDCardPresent() {
    return android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
}
```

**Edit** : As per comment, updating answer for newer versoins.

```
if(isSDCardPresent() && System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE") != null) { 
    Log.d("sd_status",""adcard available);
} else { 
    Log.d("sd_status", "sdcard not available"); 
}
```

Comment: for my HTC Nexus 9 it always give true but reality is that I have no sdcard in my phone!!!!!!!    
So how to solve this ?

Comment: This is old answer, it was the time when phone used to come with SDCARD, afaik Nexus devices have internal storage not sdcard. Hence the behavior.

Comment: thanks @AAnkit      
Now I solve this problem using this logic      

if(isSDCardPresent && System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE") != null) { Log.d("sd_status",""adcard available)} else { Log.d("sd_status", "sdcard not available") }

Answer (score 1):

Check this code also. And, change this code to whatever you want?

```
String Videopath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/whatever you want for folder name";

public void saveScreenshot() 
    {
        if (ensureSDCardAccess()) 
        {
            File file = new File(Videopath + "/" + "your file name" + "your extension");
            FileOutputStream fos;
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e("Panel", "FileNotFoundException", e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Panel", "IOEception", e);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Helper method to ensure that the given path exists.
     * TODO: check external storage state
     */
    private boolean ensureSDCardAccess() {
        File file = new File(mScreenshotPath);
        if (file.exists()) {
            return true;
        } else if (file.mkdirs()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Try this. It may be helps you.

And, check your sdcard detecting condition with this also.

I've taken these method from [Droid Nova's WebSite](http://www.droidnova.com/how-to-create-and-save-a-screenshot-from-a-surfaceview,880.html). Check that example Also.

Answer (score 1):

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if (!state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
   {
      Toast.makeText(Context, "NO EXTERNAL STORAGE FOUND",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
else
   {
     //Your code                
  }
```